# iOS - Objective-C: application crash on iOS 10 after libraries upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I have an older `Objective-C` application that I upgraded recently in order to add new functionalities. I'm using now `AFNetworking` version 4.0. All is working now even in the newest version of `iOS` except on `iOS 10`. When I run it on the simulator, the application crash immediately in the `splashSreen`. From the logs I know that it's in relation with `NSURLSession` but can't figure out how to solve it. I've found similar issues but there solutions are not up-to-date.

This is what I have in the `thread stack` when the crash happened

[image]

[image]

And this is the crash description from the console log with some previous `Firebase` calls:

```
2020-11-19 18:48:11.257 myApp[63563:2715840] Appdelegate, applicationDidBecomeActive 
Nov 19 18:48:11  myApp[63563] <Warning>: 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement 
Nov 19 18:48:11  myApp[63563] <Notice>: 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled 
Nov 19 18:48:11  myApp[63563] <Notice>: 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist 
2020-11-19 18:48:11.645 myApp[63563:2715921] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fa48d318df0 of class __NSCFLocalDataTask was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x600000031ce0> ( <NSKeyValueObservance 0x60000024a200: Observer: 0x6080000f5980, Key path: state, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x608000253ad0> )'
        *** First throw call stack: (   
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000112558141 objc_exception_throw + 48 
2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000112b5c625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197 
3 Foundation 0x000000010fb52b53 NSKVODeallocate + 294 
4 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000011256cb8e _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 202 
5 libsystem_blocks.dylib 0x0000000113ff799d _Block_release + 111 
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f6405c _dispatch_client_callout + 8 
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f40c6e _dispatch_continuation_pop + 1020 
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f4e5db _dispatch_source_invoke + 1401 
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f42c47 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 981 
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f43669 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1084 
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f45ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634 
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000113f45bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123 
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000011430d6d5 _pthread_wqthread + 220 
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000011430d57b start_wqthread + 15 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Looks like a Firebase issue, not AFNetworking: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6782

Comment: @koen thank you. I edited the title and I will check this

Comment: Try to catch it using Exception Breakpoint

Comment: @VadimZhuk this is what I get: Thread 3 Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit (concurrent). libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
->  0x104422111 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp. And the last log in the console is: <Notice>: 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist

Comment: On what line does it crash? See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/how-to-add-exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: @koen the crash is not on a specific line. It seems like there is a problem with Firebase performance. When I remove the performance pod, the app worked fine. It's not a good solution because I need the performance in the firebase console but still now I didn't find any other solution. See here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6782